# how to update excelsheet using java jxl

Tags: jxl

I want to update my existing excelsheet using java jxl.I gone through many links but not found the solution  please refer

Before update excelsheet screenshoot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2LNz.png]

after update excelsheet screenshoot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMivW.png]

```
public void  writeExcel() {

        String xlFilePath="test\\Resources\\Data\\dataExcel.xls";
        String sheetName="loginSheet";


Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlFilePath));
        WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), existingWorkbook);
        WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(sheetName);
WritableCell cell;
        Label label = new Label(2, 4, "value");
        cell = (WritableCell) label;
        sheetToEdit.addCell(label);
        workbookCopy.write();
        workbookCopy.close();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: Hello fxm,I got many link which create new  excesheet and then write on data on it.But my issue is I have to write data in same excelsheet whithout creating new excelsheet